# Angular2, load server side json file each time page is accessed

Tags: angular

Hope that I am barking down the right path, but I had a question regarding Angular2 / Node / Webpack and having one of the pages that you created access a file on the server side to chart the contents.

I am new to Angular2 and am slowly working my way to learn more and more about it, and one of the projects I am trying to work on to help me with this learning is to transition a 'self service' page that I have for product license counts.

The page was originally based on a LAMP stack and I used PHP to load my content file so that I could use jquery to render some graphs that showed how many licences were in use. That content file was json based, and was updated every hour.

I have started to convert my self service page using the following theme:

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

So far it has been going great, but of course my challenge is 'how do i read a server side file with angular2'. I started looking at the 'require(fs)' topics, but I couldn't quite get it working, so I wasn't sure if that library was actually executing server side, or client side.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is:

User clicks on link - page reads server-side json file - saves contents to variable - variable used to create jquery/angular/etc charts. - - refreshing page re-reads file.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the file over http dynamically or do want to have the file load with the angular app?

Comment: I would like it to load dynamically. This way the data is current when the content file is updated

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `fs library` cause angular runs on the client side!
Other than your PHP script was executed on the server side and then the rendered HTML was send to the client..

You could get that file via Http, see my plunker to demonstrate it: https://plnkr.co/edit/wgQOPH3DjrF67n51iHKx?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      {{data | json}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  private data: any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.get('server-side-file/data.json')
      .map(resp => resp.json())
      .subscribe(
        resp => {
          console.dir(resp);
          this.data = resp.data;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This is great! I'll have to give it a shot . One question however. Does this only load the content file when the app is initialized, or will updates to the content file be reflected as it changes? I'm assuming the former.

Comment: It will load just once, after initiation of that AppComponent. The client cannot know if any file on server was changed.. you could request that file within a timer or use something like https://socket.io to get a live connection to your backend.

Comment: You've given me some great insight.  I'll take a look at setting up a timer as well as socket.io for more info.  Thanks again.  I think I will try to combine your initial post with a timer to see how i fare.  I'll then mark as answered :)

Comment: Sure, just give it a try! If you stumble over another issue, just ask or update your question.. gl!

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, would it be bad practice to stand up a static-node server to host the content files?  It was my initial thought, where i could have my app running on port 8080, but the content sitting on a static server on 8081.  I'd have to get through the CORS hurdles, but wasn't sure if this was bad 'Node/Angular' practice.

Comment: Why do you want to serve those static files on another "server"?